# Convert PHP Script to Unix Executable File

Tags: php, linux

**Scenario | Problem**

- I have a php script ('foo.php'), which when i run with 'php foo.php' via terminal on my server executes and does what i built it to do.
- I also have another file ('bar') given to me by someone else, with no extension in its name but it's a unix executable. It runs and was coded with PHP and i'm certain of this. The sweet thing is that all i need to do to run this file is './bar'.
- I know i can get my 'foo.php' to also become executable by adding '#!/usr/bin/env php' to the top of the file and chmod u+x it and even go ahead and remove the php extension.
- However, when i open 'bar' with a text editor, all i see is gibberish (might i point out it doesn't look like it's encoded, it's actual pure gibberish as i know what encoded looks like as i've tried encoding with Zend & IonCube and the code just becomes Letters and numbers, bytecode etc). Sort of like opening a .exe file with notepad++.
- But, when I open 'foo.php' with a text editor, my source code is visible.

**Questions**

- In simple terms, I want my source php code to be invincible or come off as gibberish to any text editor whilst still being able to run it by merely './foo'.
- The other thing i've tried is use Ioncube to encode 'foo.php'. So, if i follow through using Ioncube to encode and obsfucate, how do i make the encoded 'foo.php' run by merely using './foo' in terminal.

Comment: Do you have php CLI installed ?

Answer (score 0):

> The other thing i've tried is use Ioncube to encode 'foo.php'. So, if i follow through using Ioncube to encode and obsfucate, how do i make the encoded 'foo.php' run by merely using './foo' in terminal.

The same way as before you obfuscated it.

Rename it, chmod it, add a shebang to as the first line.